# Rails style guide for render using double or single quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been reading a few books, blogs and open source code and I have a Rails style guide question.

Is the popular consensus using single quotes when using the the rendering partials.

```
<%= render 'posts' %>
```

or

```
<%= render "posts" %>
```

Some books actually use both on their coding examples.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: I am not sure if there is such convention on that. But since a partial will rarely be dynamic, using single quotes should be ok most of the time.

Comment: I tend to avoid to put too many conventions. In my opinion, this point doesn't deserve any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing to mention here is that single quote strings are slightly more efficient than double qoute strings.

Double quote strings get interpolated:

```
"Hello #{@name}!"
# => "Hello Chris!"
```

Single quote strings don't:

```
'Hello #{@name}!'
# => 'Hello #{@name}!'
```

This gives single quote strings a slight edge in speed during execution. But don't worry about it too much: The speed gain is really really small.

Answer (score 2):

you might want to check out the efforts for style guides at https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide where the reason for using double quotes refers to interpolation reasons.